# Jordan Canonical Forms: Different Approaches

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $\dim(V)=n$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$. The Jordon canonical form of a linear transformation $T\colon V\rightarrow V$ can be obtained in the following way.

1) Let $c_T(x)=(x-\lambda_1)^{m_1}(x-\lambda_2)^{m_2}\cdots (x-\lambda_r)^{m_r}$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T$. Then

2) $V=\ker(T-\lambda_1I)^{n_1} \oplus \ker(T-\lambda_2I)^{n_2}\oplus \cdots\oplus\ker(T-\lambda_rI)^{n_r}$.

3) It is sufficient to find a canonical basis for each component $\ker(T-\lambda_iI)^{n_i}$. For it, consider the chain
$$0 \subset \ker(T-\lambda_iI) \subset \ker(T-\lambda_iI)^{2} \subset \cdots \subset  \ker(T-\lambda_iI)^{n_i}=\ker(T-\lambda_iI)^{n_i+1}$$

Denote this chain by $$0 \subset K_{\lambda_i}^1 \subset K_{\lambda_i}^2 \cdots \subset K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i}.$$

4) Let $e_{n_i,1},e_{n_i,2},\ldots, e_{n_i,q_i}$ be a basis of $K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i}$ modulo $K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i-1}$. Apply $T-\lambda_iI$ on these vectors, to obtain $n_i$ linearly independent vectors in $K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i-1}$:
$$(T-\lambda_iI)e_{n_i,1},(T-\lambda_iI)e_{n_i,2},\ldots, (T-\lambda_iI)e_{n_i,q_i}.$$

Extend this set to a basis of $K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i-1}$ modulo $K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i-2}$, say 
$$(*)\qquad (T-\lambda_iI)e_{n_i,1},(T-\lambda_iI)e_{n_i,2},\ldots, (T-\lambda_iI)e_{n_i,q_i}, e_{n_i,q_i+1}, \ldots, e_{n_i,q_i+t_i}$$

5) Repeat step 4 for the set $(*)$. The unions of basis of $K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i}/K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i-1}, K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i-1}/K_{\lambda_i}^{n_i-2},\ldots, K_{\lambda_i}^{1}/0$ will give a canonical basis for the component $\ker(T-\lambda_iI)^{n_i}$.

**Question** Do anyone knows a standard or elementary textbook reference for this method? I couldn't find any intuition/ idea behind the proof. It will be better if one suggests some simple example to illustrate this procedure.

I know the only following [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=v9NekVwQdWEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Linear%20Algebra%20Bhattacharya%20Jain%20?Nagpaul&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R7QbVcuXBIKpuQS_lIDQCw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Linear%20Algebra%20Bhattacharya%20Jain%20%3FNagpaul&f=false):

Comment: Peter Lax's Linear Algebra and Its Applications has this construction in the appendix I think.

Comment: Note that "canonical basis" in point 5) is completely out of place. While the form of the matrix is canonical, the basis is very far from canonical. While there is [discussion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical) about what "canonical" means in general, there must be _something_ that puts a canonical thing apart from arbitrary similar things in its class. Here there is just nothing of that.

Answer (score 0):

Check Halmos "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces" classic (1958 or 1974 reprint), section 58.  It may be phrased differently than your approach, but it is essentially the same method.